# How to rerun resolvers when queryParams change

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-router

I'm working on it for days, But doesn't find any solution so far.

I've got a resolver service, which's supposed to return an ***Observable*** :

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<any>|Promise<any>{
    return Observable.forkJoin(
         this.http.get(first call with queryParam),
         this.http.get(second call with queryParam),             
    );
}
```

I subscribe to my ActivatedRoute data in the component, and it's working pretty well.

BUT, as you can see in the code above, my component has a *queryParam*, and my API calls depend on this *queryParam*. When I manually change it, it doesn't "resolve" the route again.

I completely understand why, I read the documentation.

Does anyone has a workaround ? Is this even possible to subscribe to params and return an Observable in this situation ?

I tried this so far, but it doesn't return an Observable, so it does nothing :

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => { 
    if(event instanceof ResolveEnd){
      // My previous Observable.forkJoin
    }
});
```

Thank you :) !

**-----------**
**SOLUTION (thanks Maximus) :** **-----------**

Add in the routing :

```
{
   path: 'some path',
   runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
   ...
}
```

Then, no need to subscribe to route event or anything ! Magic !

Comment: Since your data changes according to your queryParams, the subscription to the queryParams must be in the ngOnInit. Resolver are good for Data that does not change.

Comment: Yes, that's what is implemented at the moment. My problem is that i've got ~ 8 api calls that are supposed to build many things. I don't think there is a solution to my " issue ", but I prefer asking..

Comment: Did you tried to navigateByUrl ? I think this forces the component the re-resolve the data. Note : this does not solve the problem of your  8 api calls

Comment: I'm not very familiar with navigateByUrl. I'm reading some doc, thanks :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `runGuardsAndResolvers` for the route. Here is what the official docs say:

> ... defines when guards and resolvers will be run.
>   By default they run only when the matrix parameters of the route
>   change. When set to paramsOrQueryParamsChange they will also run when
>   query params change. And when set to always, they will run every time.

So when defining a route you can use it like this:

```
{
   path: 'some path',
   runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
   ...
}
```

This should re-run guards and resolvers.

Comment: Waw, never heard of this. I read the official doc, I think it's exactly what I need. I'm gonna test it and edit my answer if I can reach what I want, thank you !!

Comment: I tried, is works PERFECTLY. Exactly what I needed ! I edit my question with your answser. Many thanks